# Share image with my app

Tags: ios, swift

i would like to share image with my app, like Facebook, whatsapp or many other app... i use this code:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Icon-22x29.png</string>
            <string>Icon-44x58.png</string>
            <string>Icon-64x64.png</string>
            <string>Icon-320x320.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My App</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.image</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The problem is that when i click share photos, from photo app or from email app, my app does not appear, whats wrong?

If i use com.adbobe.pdf and share pdf it appear!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the document types that your application can open with iOS. To do this you need to add a document type to your app’s Info.plist for each document type that your app can open. Additionally if any of the document types are not known by iOS, you will need to provide an Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) for that document type.

refer [How do I get my application to show up in the "Open in..." menu on iOS for a specific document type?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html) for detail description!